# can I splice underground 12-2 UF cable run to a water pump

Tags: electrical, wiring

Can I run 12-2 NM-B wire from my 20 amp dedicated breaker under my house and then using a four by four box splice 12-2 UF wire to run underground to my water pump house?

Running the wire would be in a dry crawl space, and the 4 x 4 box that the splice will be will also be in the dry crawl space mounted to a floor beam.

Comment: When you say "*under my house*". Do you mean in a dry basement/crawlspace, or under a slab/damp crawlspace?

Comment: When you say 'under my house', do you mean like running through a crawlspace? And would the junction box be under the house too, mounted to the wall outside, or buried?

Comment: Running the wire would be in a dry crawl space and the 4 x 4 box that the splice will be will also be in the dry crawl space mounted to a floor beam. I'm not sure I placed this in the right place or if I should have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can splice the NM above ground in a box above ground then run the UF to your pump. The depth for UF cable to be buried as you exit the foundation is 24” per NEC table 300.5.

Comment: You can splice the NM in a box above ground, in a **dry** location.